# Django login - getting an AttributeError can't set attribute

Tags: django, mongodb, attributeerror

I'm getting the following error every time I attempt to login on the local copy of my Django site:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/process_login/

Django Version: 1.4
Python Version: 2.7.2
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'tweets',
 'users',
 'dashboard',
 'GChartWrapper.charts',
 'api',
 'prospector',
 'viz')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/sheldonc/Tealeaf/users/views.py" in process_login
  184.             login(request, user)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py" in login
  71.         request.session.cycle_key()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py" in cycle_key
  241.         self.create()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mongoengine-0.6.1-py2.7.egg/mongoengine/django/sessions.py" in create
  44.             self.session_key = self._get_new_session_key()

Exception Type: AttributeError at /users/process_login/
Exception Value: can't set attribute
```

And the Exception Location:

```
Exception Location: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mongoengine-0.6.1-py2.7.egg/mongoengine/django/sessions.py in create, line 44
```

Using pdb, I debugged it a bit further. In the `login(request, user)` method:

```
def login(request, user):
 56         """
 57         Persist a user id and a backend in the request. This way a user doesn't
 58         have to reauthenticate on every request. Note that data set during
 59         the anonymous session is retained when the user logs in.
 60         """
 61         if user is None:
 62             user = request.user
 63         # TODO: It would be nice to support different login methods, like signed cookies.
 64         if SESSION_KEY in request.session:
 65             if request.session[SESSION_KEY] != user.id:
 66                 # To avoid reusing another user's session, create a new, empty
 67                 # session if the existing session corresponds to a different
 68                 # authenticated user.
 69                 request.session.flush()
 70         else:
 71             request.session.cycle_key()
```

`SESSION_KEY` is None, so `request.session.cycle_key()` is called, and somewhere in there it appears the AttributeError is thrown (

Is this a problem with my mongo connection? I've been poking around but I can't seem to figure this out

Answer (score 0):

Known (and fixed) bug : https://github.com/hmarr/mongoengine/issues/469

Comment: If it's fixed and I'm updated to the latest production version of mongo (2.0.6), how can I get this to work?

Comment: @neptune : Either use a non production version or patch (or monkeypatch) your version.